# How can I deduce the type of the result of returning by reference in C++?

Tags: c++, reference

Consider:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Item {
    Item(int Value = 0, std::string AsoName = "NULL") : Value{Value}, AsoName{AsoName} {}

    int Value;
    std::string AsoName;

    auto& operator->() {
        if (/*what*/) {
            return AsoName;
        }
        else {
            return Value;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Item a(10,"Name");
    a.operator->() = "Other Name";
    a.operator->() = 5;
}
```

I'm trying to change `Value`or `AsoName` through a reference using a `->` operator, but how can I know the type of the new values "Other Name" and 5? It's just for learning purposes.

Comment: You can return a helper object that implements two overload versions of `operator=`. I don't understand why you're using `operator->` instead of a normal member function though.

Comment: its just for learning purpose  im trying many things but is there a way to do deduce the type ?

Comment: There is no easy way to do this. What are you trying to archieve? Why don't you do `a.AsoName = "Other Name"; a.Value = 5;`? -- Overloading `operator->()` is done to give your type pointer semantics, so you can do `a->/*something*/`, even though `a` is not a pointer. But therefore it must return an actual pointer, `operator->` that returns a reference is useless.

Comment: A return type can only depend on the function argument types, not on things that happen after the function returns.

Comment: `auto` doesn't mean what you think it means. It doesn't mean that each `return` can return a different type. In C++ a function can only return the same type every time. `auto` does not change that.

Comment: i already know this method but maybe my example is not clear. the main reason of this question is to know is there any method to deduce the type in this case or any simalar condition using operator or any other tools

Comment: *...is there a way to do deduce the type ?*  The problem is:  What type are you trying to deduce?  The compiler won't know that.  The type cannot be deduced this way.

Comment: You *can* have different return types selected by `if constexpr (what)` that selects one of the returns at compile time. But that cannot depend on the right hand side of the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You've got this backwards.  Replace your `operator->` member function with these:

```
Item& operator= (const std:string &s)
{
    AsoName = s;
    return *this;
}

Item& operator= (int i)
{
    Value = i;
    return *this;
}
```

And then you can do:

```
a = "Other Name";
a = 5;
```

Comment: Could also have `auto& operator->() { return *this; }` to keep the callsite invocation verbatim.  (Why?  I don't know why anyone would *want* that, but for sake of toy example of an idiosyncratic way to go about getters/setters for educational purposes.)